# Add value of the already existing key in dict in a form of container in Python

Tags: python

Is there any built-in function that would do the following?

```
dictionary = {‘a’:1, ‘b’:2, ‘c’:3}

dictionary.update(c=10)

# what happens
dictionary  ---- {‘a’:1, ‘b’:2, ‘c’:10}

# what I want to happen:
dictionary  ---- {‘a’:1, ‘b’:2, ‘c’:(3, 10)}
```

By default if keys are the same, later key would override earlier one.
If the key is already present in dict, the value of the new key: value pair would be added to already existing value in a form of container, like tuple, or list or set.

I can write a helper function to do so but I believe it should be something built-in for this matter.

Comment: That sounds like you should consistently use lists as values, rather than changing the value type when you get a second value.

Comment: Just use [`defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) instead of a vanilla dict. Also please post syntactically valid [mre]s.

Comment: @jonrsharpe there's a minor difference here, in that using a `defaultdict` or the `setdefault` method of regular `dict` objects will *both* always have the container as a value, whereas the OP starts with non-container values that then changes to values in a container when the key is added to again... this doesn't seem like a reasonable thing to do to me but it is a distinction

Comment: [werkzeug.MultiDict](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.MultiDict.html) may fit your usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
d["a"].append(1)
d["b"].append(2)
d["c"].append(3)
d["c"].append(10)

print(d)
```

Result

```
defaultdict(list, {'a': [1], 'b': [2], 'c': [3, 10]})
```

Answer (score 2):

Your desired solution is not very elegant, so I am going to propose an alternative one.

1. Tuples are immutable. Let's use lists instead, because we can easily append to them.
2. The data type of the values should be consistent. Use lists in any case, even for single values.
3. Let's use a `defaultdict` such that we don't have to initialize lists manually.

Putting it together:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for v, k in enumerate('abc', 1):
...     d[k].append(v)    
...     
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [1], 'b': [2], 'c': [3]})
>>> d['c'].append(10)
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [1], 'b': [2], 'c': [3, 10]})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite the update function by creating a new class:

In Python `bulitins.py`:

```
    def update(self, E=None, **F): # known special case of dict.update
        """
        D.update([E, ]**F) -> None.  Update D from dict/iterable E and F.
        If E is present and has a .keys() method, then does:  for k in E: D[k] = E[k]
        If E is present and lacks a .keys() method, then does:  for k, v in E: D[k] = v
        In either case, this is followed by: for k in F:  D[k] = F[k]
        """
        pass
```

So I write this(Inherit from `UserDict`, suggested by @timgeb):

```
from collections import UserDict


class CustomDict(UserDict):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def update(self, E=None, **F) -> None:
        if E:
            if isinstance(E, dict):
                for k in E:
                    self[k] = E[k]
            else:
                for k, v in E:
                    self[k] = v
        else:
            if isinstance(F, dict):
                for key in F:
                    if isinstance(self[key], list):
                        self[key].append(F[key])
                    else:
                        self[key] = [self[key], F[key]]


dictionary = CustomDict()
dictionary.update({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3})
print(dictionary)
dictionary.update(a=3)
print(dictionary)
dictionary.update(a=4)
print(dictionary)
```

Result:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
{'a': [1, 3, 4], 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

---

Maybe there are some logic errors in my code,but welcome to point out.

Comment: Consider inheriting from `collections.UserDict`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use something like:

```
dictionary = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
dictionary.update({'c': 10 if not dictionary.get('c') else tuple([dictionary['c'],] + [10,])})
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': (3, 10)}
```

But it should probably be wrapped into a function to make things clean. The general pattern would be (I suppose, based on your question):

```
dict = {...}
if 'a' not in dict:
    do_this() # just add it to the dict?
else:
    do_that() # build a tuple or list?
```

In your above question you're mixing types -- I'm not sure if you want that, a more pythonic approach might be to have all the values as list and use a `defaultdict`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. Thanks for the answer. I used defaultdict -it made code much clearer. I specially used this toy example to just explain problem in its core without any non-specific code around.